# FIX: GTX 690 Missing Dual GPU, 3D Not Detected VGA PCI Driver Issue (Windows 10)

Tags: linux, windows, drivers, hardware-failure, nvidia-graphics-card

## STORY/TRIES (See Updates 3 for FIX)

I bought a GTX 690 (Dual-GPU), used, and it worked flawlessly until the last few days; story:

I tried to install Windows Driver Kit at the same time I was creating an SQL database and my PC froze. Everything was froze so I had to do a hard shutdown/reset. When I booted back into W11, 2nd monitor was all black/closed, Device Manager had a yellow warning sign next to "Display Adapters", for the GTX 690.

What I had tried:

- *Rolling back the drivers; didn't work, same glitch*
- *Re-installing the NVIDIA drivers; didn't work, same glitch*
- *I then re-installed the OS from scratch, didn't work, even w/ NVIDIA's drivers.*
- *Re-image from a confirmed working W10/11 image, 2nd screen still black, not working.*
- *I re-installed the OS another time, but w/ main drive wiped using Secure Erase+ (AMD).*
- *Tried to boot in safe mode, using DDU to wipe all drivers, then re-install clean ones; still bugs.*
- *Tried to re-install many versions of the drivers, didn't work.*

Everytime I install the NVIDIA's drivers, after the installation (2-5 seconds after progress bar ends); I get a notification from Windows: **"Force to reinstall graphics driver."**

- If I don't manually set the driver on "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter" or reboot the computer, it goes in a loop of notifications, constantly sound glitching and "trying" to use the NVIDIA's GPU driver but it fails and tries again indefinitely (unless I set it to MS' Basic Adapter)

Stuff that may have broken the drivers >

- (Kali was installed with poor firewall config)
- NVIDIA's Control Panel doesn't want to open, after many re-installs, even the one in the Windows Store. (Multiple OS reinstalls/same problem) After the "Agree & continue button"; dead process, can't open. I cannot even right-click the Desktop, the NVIDIA container option is not there, after many reinstalls.

[Windows10GPUs-Glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpEoy.png)

Comment: Are their even Windows 11 drivers for your GPU. Code 43 typically means device is detected but not functional due to drivers

Comment: I re-installed under Windows 10, to make sure it wasn't the OS, but it still fails to install the drivers. I just spent 4 hours installing Kali with nvidia-smi, it seems to work, the two displays are working, don't know why Windows is acting so weird.

Comment: Update: 1. GPU Cleaned (had lots of dust in it), 2. Applied new thermal paste (small dots), 3. Reflashed MB with newest BIOS, 4. DDU/Reinstall (didn't work), 5. On the reboot, I've been able to sucessfully install the drivers and show two GPUs (NVIDIA GTX 690) but as soon as I saw that I right-clicked the Desktop for the NVIDIA Control Panel and my PC re-froze. Had to hard-reboot, on login, driver was faulty again (Code 43) and neither DDU or Linux would detect the two dies (GPUs). Any advices? Seems like a dead GPU to be (1/2), would it still be usable under Linux? (SMI detects one GPU - 2GB)

Comment: I've been able to get two monitor in Windows but only for 1 minute, as soon as the two GPUs have been detected in the Device Manager (right after installing the driver 416.94) then I went to Desktop to right-click and open the NCP, but PC froze. Never been able to get the 2nd GPU again. Any help/feedback is welcome.

Comment: Why are you now talking about a 2nd GPU your question only makes mention of a single GPU? Why are you providing updates in a comment instead of performing an [edit] on your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update 3... & possible FIX!

## Well after a week I've figured out. The problem is half-solved but at least, I can play games now. Here is some more information to help y'all fix it:

### *** If your GPU is already able to get multi-monitor display on Windows 8.1/10, you may not need to install Windows 8.1. You can skip to #4. This tutorial is aimed at those **NOT able** to get a second/third monitor display on their 690's. ***

**Linux Tutorial:**

> forums.kali.org/showthread.php?35748-TUTORIAL-Installing-official-NVIDIA-driver-in-Optimus-laptop

| Config | Screen 0 | Screen 1 | GPU Detected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Linux | Yes: 270.26+ | Yes: 270.26+ | Yes: GPU-0 (Half-memory) |
| Win8 | Yes: 310.70+ | Yes: 310.70+ | Yes: GPU-0 & 1 (Half-memory) |
| Win10 | Yes: 472.98 | Yes: 472.98 | Yes: GPU-0 & 1 (Doesn't detect 2nd GPU after 2 boots/No force reinstall/3D works) |

- The card has GPUs on two PCI buses: (mine is 43 & 44), sometimes, the 44th PCI bus doesn't detect the GPU, but games still runs (2 out of 4GB available), still usable for games.
- NVIDIA Control Panel (W10) - Turn off Multi-GPU mode, assign GPU-0 to PhysX

#### Optional but recommended; NVIDIA's Latest Drivers:

#### (https://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx)

- Windows 8.1 ISO : https://www.microsoft.com/fr-ca/software-download/windows8)
- Windows 8.1 Old Drivers [310.70] : https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/54625/en-us
- **Windows 10 [DCH] : https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/186165/en-us**
- Linux x86_64 Old Drivers [270.26] : https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/270.26/
- **DDU v18.0.4.9 : https://www.wagnardsoft.com/DDU/download/DDU%20v18.0.4.9.exe**
- *It is a good idea to download more than 1 old driver to test it out (W8/Linux) & clean your GPU.
- ***I did the Linux tutorial first (displays all works on Debian), then W8, and W10.***
- **System Image Backup** of your computer incase of a ***complex driver failure.*** (Control Panel > View by: Small icons > Backup and Restore [Windows 7] > Create system image)
- Once everything is downloaded, **unplug the Ethernet cable from the computer [REQUIRED].**

## Windows 8.1 GPU Test >

1. Install Windows 8.1 (from Microsoft's Website..), on a seperate *(test)* partition of main SSD.
2. Install GPU drivers **[310.70-desktop-win8-win7-winvista-64bit-english-whql]** on Windows 8.1.
3. Test the GPU performance - If not working, may be an hardware issue.

- If no 2nd display, check with hardware manufacturer/technician. It may be damaged (old card).
- *Out of 4-5 different Drivers Installs on W10*, none had worked.
- All prompted the "Force to reinstall driver dialog".
- ***It somehow got fixed for W8.1, let's now try in Windows 10!***
- (My 690 played COD:BO3 fine, sounded GOOD/OK) [1 GPU Detected, but no driver glitch like in W10]

## Windows 10 Procedure >

4. Switch to Windows 10, & **roll back/uninstall the (broken) NVIDIA driver, if not already done.**

- *Device Manager - Display Adapter - Properties - Driver - Uninstall Device.*
- *[x] tick the "Delete the driver software for this device."*

5. On Windows 10 (Microsoft Display Driver), **install NVIDIA's 310.70 driver.**

- *After the installation, you should get a* ***BSoD (driver error).***
- **Let the computer restart, until it goes into "Auto-Repair" mode. This is where the 2nd GPU might/will get/got re-detected!!**

***-> Once finished, it should tell you that it cannot start Windows.***

- **(will/should start normally after a simple restart.)**
- *This is where a backup is useful if the computer doesn't reboot sucessfully.*

6. Boot into ***Safe Mode***: *Run > msconfig > Boot > Tick "Safe Mode" > Reboot.*
7. *In Safe Mode*, **extract DDU, run it**, ***remove all the NVIDIA's drivers & DO NOT RESTART (2nd Button).***
8. ***Set Reboot into Normal Mode:*** *Run > msconfig > Boot > Untick "Safe Mode" > Reboot.*
9. Back into **Normal W10**, now it's time to ***try*** the ***freshest/newest*** drivers.
10. *Run the DCH driver install:* **[472.98-desktop-win10-win11-64bit-international-dch-whql]** ***(newest secure driver up to this day.)***
11. Install **ONLY** the NVIDIA Drivers (No GeForce Experience); Custom; Components; untick all, ONLY keep: NVIDIA's Driver, PhysX Driver & "Fresh Installation." [See Picture]

[Drivers-Procedure.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWDtR.png)

12. On completion, the screen will refresh/flicker a couple time and the driver glitch should be gone.

- If it isn't, it brings us back to hardware failure or heavy software corruption, which may be solved by talking to an NVIDIA's tech guy or some wizards. Try some troubleshooting in Linux with **nvidia-smi** & **nvflash** to get insights on your GPU if that can help. Be careful though, it's a powerful tool! Don't brick your half-working card...
- NVIDIA Control Panel (W10) - Turn off Multi-GPU mode, assign GPU-0 to PhysX

> nvflash - techpowerup.com/download/nvidia-nvflash/

> nvidia-smi is included in the driver bundle from NVIDIA (Linux):

> download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/270.26/

Hopefully your problem have been fixed and you saved a card! ***If you didn't, don't lose hope, I think you can still setup a mining rig on this **leftover GK104 die**, since Linux does detect it, with 1999MB VRAM available.*** *I have not done this before, but it could help on buying a new card hehe! Have a great day everyone =)*

*The 2nd GPU die GK104 (PCI Bus 44) stopped being detected but at least the drivers installed correctly and it let me use 3D. Might be an hardware issue, or Windows being picky.

Comment: Why are you crying like this?